# How do I prevent a Slotted HTML element from rendering until is it inside the shadowRoot?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

I have a very simple site similar to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg9bmxwr/10/). Everything seems to work fine but on my local one, but when I stop at the first JS line (before the custom elements are declared) I can see the div with no formatting...

```
<jrg-test>
  <div slot="test">
      This should work
  </div>
</jrg-test>

connectedCallback() {
  console.log("Ok we are working")
  this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = "<slot name='test'></slot>"
  const element = document.createElement('style');
  element.textContent = "::slotted(*){background-color:red;color:white;}";
  this.shadowRoot.appendChild(element);
}
```

So basically if I stop before the custom element is rendered I see the raw div. I know there are some hacky solutions involving positioning and CSS but is there a cleaner solution. Possibly one I can implement exclusively in JS?

So the main question is how can I hide the `This should work` text until the red background and white color have been applied?

Comment: Have you tried applying the css inline on the div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try to use the `:defined` CSS pseudo-class to hide the custom element while it's defined.

See the example below:

```js
class TestElement extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super();
    console.log("Attaching the shadow")
    this.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log("Ok we are working")
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<style>
      ::slotted(*){background-color:red;color:white;}
      </style>
      <slot name='test'></slot>`
  }
}
upgrade.onclick = () => customElements.define("jrg-test", TestElement)
```

```css
jrg-test:not(:defined) {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<jrg-test>
  <div slot="test">This should work</div>
</jrg-test>

<button id="upgrade">upgrade</button>
```

Comment: Interesting is this supported across all modern browsers?

Comment: @Jackie yes I think so (tested in Chrome/Opera, Firefox, new Edge, Opera). I don't have Safari

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all not defined customElements with adding to global styles

```
<style>
   *:not(:defined) { display:none }
</style>
```

For example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> *:not(:defined) { display:none } </style>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <test-tag>
        This content will be visible only after "test-tag" is defined
    </test-tag>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: global CSS will only hide Custom Elements in the main Document; this CSS will not hide undefined elements in shadowRoots